# Сколько экземпляров синглетона может быть в одной JVM?

Tags: java

Наткнулся в [этой статье](http://habrahabr.ru/post/203688/) на данный вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, про что именно спрашивают и в какой области искать ответ. Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Там же написано - суть в загрузчиках классов (classloader).

JVM идентифицирует классы по имени класса и имени загрузчика. То есть, если класс `Foo` загрузить двумя разными загрузчиками, мы будем иметь в JVM две версии класса `Foo`.

Соответственно, если `Foo` представляет собой синглетон - у нас будет два синглетона.

Comment: +1, но. Строго говоря, если в принципе возможно создать более одного экземпляра, то это **не синглтон**.

Если считать, как JVM, классы с разным загрузчиком _разными_, то у нас будет не два инстанса синглтона, а по одному инстансу _разных_ синглтонов. Если считать, в отличие от JVM, классы с разным загрузчиком одинаковыми, то _в Java синглтон невозможен_.

Comment: @VladD, да, говоря, что "у нас будет два синглетона", я подразумевал не два экземпляра, а два разных синглетона.